# find a word in this text

Tags: cipher

I have two "messages":

596f752061726520616c6d6f7374207468657265203b29
aHR0cDovLzE5My4xNDIuMTEyLjIyMDo5MC9tYWluX3Rhc2sucGRm

They have a hidden password, and I don't know exactly which one could have this pass (maybe both)?

As I found, the first password consists of numbers and letters from 'a' to 'f' so maybe it has something to do with hex?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks more like an assignment than a puzzle.

Comment: I can repost this in Crypto.

Answer (score 7):

The first one is [**hex-encoded ASCII**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), and translates to:

> You are almost there ;)

The second is [**base64**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), and translates to:

> http://193.142.112.220:90/main_task.pdf